# The image of a horizontal line Im(z)=pi/4 for the complex number f(z)=e^z

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function, graphing-functions

I tried to plot the image of the line $Im(z)=\pi/4$, for the complex number $f(z)=e^z$.

I wrote first the complex number as w=u+iv:

$w=e^x\cdot e^{-iy}$

$Im(z)=\pi/4$ means that y in the equation is $\pi/4$, so that gives:

$Im(z)=e^{-i\pi/4}=\cos(\pi/4)-i\sin(\pi/4)$

then

$w=e^x(\cos(\pi/4)-i\sin(\pi/4))=e^x\cos(\pi/4)-e^xi\sin(\pi/4)$

Plotting this in a w-plane , I thought it would be the line at  $-i\sin(\pi/4)=-\sqrt{2}/2$, but I actually just replotted the z-geometry again. See image below.

How do I do this right?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Note that your second $Im(z)$ is not correct. It should be just $e^{-iy}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $z=x+\frac\pi4i$, then$$\exp(z)=e^x\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}\right).$$Since $\{e^x\mid x\in\Bbb R\}=(0,\infty)$, $\left\{\exp\left(x+\frac\pi 4i\right)\,\middle|\,x\in\Bbb R\right\}$ is the open ray with origin in $0$ and passing through $\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}$.

Comment: Thanks! How can one spot the "ray" from 0 by this and how does this ray look like?

Comment: Take the line $\{x+xi\mid x\in\Bbb R\}$. This ray is the upper half of that line, that is, the set $\{x+xi\mid x>0\}$. That's so because, if $\lambda>0$, then$$\lambda\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}\right)=\frac\lambda{\sqrt2}+\frac\lambda{\sqrt2}i,$$and $\frac\lambda{\sqrt2}>0$. And, if $x>0$,$$x+xi=x\sqrt2\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}\right),$$which is of the form $\lambda\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}$, with $\lambda>0$.

Comment: Thanks for this! So when you construct a w-plane graph, you take into account the whole z=x+iy. x+iy is a line that goes from the origin and up like y=x on the real plot. Indeed the line has an argument of $\pi/4$, but I don't follow once this is related to e^z. How do  I know it is the upper half of the line $(arg(\pi∕4 - arg\pi/2$) that is the ray?

Comment: Because, as I proved, the image of $\left\{x+\frac\pi4i\,\middle|\,x\in\Bbb R\right\}$ with respect to the exponential function is the set $\{y+yi\mid y>0\}$.

Comment: Is there a software or online program to sketch these images?

Comment: You can use GeoGebra to do that.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that

Comment: One last question, in the w-plane, is the x axis u and y-axis iv ? (from w=u+iv)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131781/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-vqngs).